# Using Crconfig.xml for web application

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, crystal-reports

I am making a web application. This web application makes reports and gets data with a jdbc connection. My problem is configuring the JDBC connection to Oracle.

I am assuming I need to use CRConfig.xml. I am reading the documentation about it, but i can't seem to find anything that concerns the use of this file in a web application.

I have seen a lot and a lot of examples that references a file that is just an absolute path, which may seem to be a problem when deploying the project in another server.

Am I missing a fact here? Am I looking at the right place?

Answer (score 0):

For a Java web application, the CRConfig.xml file should be placed in the /WEB-INF/classes folder of the WAR.  [Here is a PDF document written by SAP](https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/index?rid=/library/uuid/b0348c83-b81d-2b10-3bb3-95bd52350eb4&overridelayout=true) with more details about when the file is needed.